# How to study quantum machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to make my quantum machine learning algorithms. As far as I understand I must learn: basics of quantum physics, quantum computing (and algorithms), classical machine learning, quantum information; anything else?

And from where would you advise me to start studying?

Do I really need to learn quantum computing or do you have some books or helpful sources?

I will be very grateful!

Comment: **Related:** [Introductory material for quantum machine learning](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/introductory-material-for-quantum-machine-learning). BTW you don't need to learn quantum information to study QML. All the basics you need to get started is there in Nielsen and Chuang's textbook. On the side, you could start reading the review papers on this subject. I've also heard good things about [Wittek's textbook](https://peterwittek.com/book.html) although I haven't read it. (I will try to elaborate on this in an answer later.)

Comment: To start with: What do you know?

Comment: quantum machine learning, if meant in the sense of applying quantum algorithms to solve problems analogous to those solve by classical machine learning algorithms (such as pattern recognition and such), is essentially a subfield of quantum computing. So I would say yes, you definitely need to learn quantum computing as a requirement. (Unless of course by QML you mean other things, such as applying classical machine learning to problems arising in quantum mechanics)

Answer (score 4):

There are different review overviews about Quantum Machine Learning (see the question referenced in comments to find a few) but it is an evolving field so you will have to keep updated. There is also an [EDX online course about the subject made by Wittek](https://www.edx.org/course/quantum-machine-learning) recently released if you would like a little more hands-on format.

I would advise to start with basics of quantum computing (like the basic linear algebra, notions of measurement...), check in parallel classical Machine Learning and cross-ref with what quantum versions of ML algorithms have been proposed so far.

Comment: I'm currently enrolled in Wittek's course and it's good. Supervised Learning with Quantum Computers by Schuld is also a good reference.

Comment: How much time did you spent until you were able to make some algorithms?

Comment: I would say it is a continuous process. One picks an algo, try to get the required notions and implement if possible. Then you pick another and you continue. For me, I would take a month or two per algo and implementation.