# Resources on quantum machine learning for beginners

Tags: resource-request, machine-learning

I am a first year PhD Physics student, working on quantum information theory. I am planning to learn machine learning and in particular quantum machine learning. I do not have any prior exposure to machine learning. I am also a beginner in the field of quantum information theory. Can anyone please advice how should I proceed for this, given my background? Any suggestion of textbooks/lectures/reference materials would be helpful.

Comment: Resources to learn Quantum Computing and QML

https://monitsharma.github.io/Learn-Quantum-Computing-For-Free/

Just search for Quantum Machine Learning on this page

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2151/55