Reference recommendation for research in quantum algorithm and quantum machine learning?
I have finished reading Nielson and Chuang and am interested in doing research in quantum algorithm and quantum machine learning. Are there any references that introduce these topics at research level? References that contain exercises and problems are preferred. Beginner projects on these topics also help. Thank you.

does https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2151/55 answer your question? If not, can you clarify how your question differs from that one?
